# Can we work on both (After) and (InsteadOf) Triggers in SQL on a single table?

Tags: sql-server

We can create any type of triggers on a single table . But the thing is if we have Instead Of Trigger created on a table untill and unless it is disabled or deleted we cannot work on After Triggers.At a single strech we cannot work on both the types. Can anyone guide me over this? Whether is it possible or not to work with two triggers(After and InsteadOf) in a single table?

Comment: If you have, say, both 'instead of insert' and 'after insert' triggers on the same table and your 'instead of' trigger does not insert anything into that very table, then your 'after' trigger will never fire. Is that your case?

Answer (score 3):

You certainly can have both instead of and after triggers on the same table:

```
create table dbo.T1 (
 ID int not null,
 Val1 varchar(10) not null
)
create table dbo.T1_History (
 ID int not null,
 Val1 varchar(10) not null,
 HappenedAt datetime not null
)
go
create trigger T_T1_I
on dbo.T1
instead of insert
as
 insert into dbo.T1 (ID,Val1)
 select ID+10,Val1 from inserted
go
create trigger T_T1_I_History
on dbo.T1
after insert
as
 insert into dbo.T1_History (ID,Val1,HappenedAt)
 select ID,Val1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from inserted
go
insert into dbo.T1 (ID,Val1)
select 1,'abc'
go
select * from dbo.T1
select * from dbo.T1_History
```

Obviously, you can only have a single instead of trigger, but you can have multiple after triggers.

I'm afraid your question does seem a little unclear - I'm not sure what the phrase:

> if we have Instead Of Trigger created on a table until and unless it is disabled or deleted we cannot work on After Triggers

is meant to mean.